# Standard GNU-style keyword options

Tags: linux, unix, gnu, getopt, getopts

The book "The Art of UNIX Programming" by Eric Raymond has a section entitled "The `-a` to `-z` of command line options", in which he enumerates a "semantic standard" of what various single-letter flags are expected to mean.

For example `-a` usually means all, `-d` usually means debug and `-f` usually means file.

Is there anything similar for GNU-style keyword options, that is long multi-letter options preceded by two hythens (`--`)?

In particular, I was looking for the GNU-style equivalents of `-f` and `-o` with the meanings input file and output file respectively.

Would the former option be `--file`?
Would the latter option be `--output`?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly most of the GNU programmers uses `--output` or `-o` for output file.

In addition for the long parameters generally more detailed and description need parameters uses two hyphens.